# Is it safe in Git to pre-merge master into my feature branch before final merge?

Tags: git, git-branch

While developing a feature branch locally, it turned out the feature needs huge changes. In order to minimize the amount of work and stress during the merge, I thought of first merging locally master into my branch, resolve all conflicts, and then merge my feature into master - which should then be a fast forward, easy merge.

Does this merge expose any risk of losing someone's changes? Do you recommend another approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I typically rebase the features on top of master, this makes it easier for the person who needs to merge them. However no matter in what direction you do it - even when you get no merge conflicts you still need to test it. You can never asume it is safe.

Comment: Rebase rewrites history, so my understanding is that it's ok just for the first time, until my local changes land in repo.Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, if the commits have been pushed, rebase shouldn't be used (there are exceptions, e.g. if you are sure, that nobody else has fetched and used your branch, then you could use rebase and do a forced push).

Comment: I dont see a problem in rebasing feature branches. Especially since nobody would branch from them. But if you want to be extra carefull you can push the rebased change as a new branch. However most tools (like Gerrit or Github PR) allow/expect you update the existing branches.

Answer (score 2):

This approach is totally acceptable (and i used it myself a few times for the same reason you mentioned). Of course, when you resolve conflicts, you have to take care what changes you keep. If you make some mistakes here, then changes from other devs might be lost (but they are always kept in the history, so you can easily identify and recover that changes).

Answer (score 0):

I would only do it if the feature branch is **not** about to be merged into master. I'd recommend merging upstream regularly into the feature branch in order to minimize work required for merges during and after development. However, if you merge back, there is no point in merging one way and then immediately the other way. Simply merging into master makes your intention clearer.

Another reason for me for merging upstream into the feature branch is, sometimes, e.g., after another feature has been merged into upstream, the branches are so diverged that I need at least one commit after the merge in order to make everything work again. This is something that should be done on the feature branch.

Because all those operations are quick and cheap, I usually try to merge into master and if I see that this is just more work than expected, I abort and make the merge the other way around.

Oh, and as to losing stuff: You'll never lose something one way or the other except you remove it yourself. Git will not throw away any changes except you tell it to (removing stuff during a merge, using a non-default merge strategy, etc.).